# Run Workflow Rule only on published knowledge article

Tags: workflow, knowledge

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181118&type=1
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h1cmAAA

When you publish a knowledge article, Salesforce:

1. Saves the draft
2. Runs Workflow Rules
3. Publishes that saved draft.

So when you click Publish on a draft, the Workflow Rule will evaluate PublicationStatus as "Draft", not "Published".

How can I have a Workflow Rule only fire if the user is publishing the draft, not just saving a new version of the draft without publishing? I can't think of any workaround, no matter how ridiculous. Maybe a useless Approval Process that is used only for this?

Comment: A terrible workaround I can think of is making a "Publishing" field that the user would check that my workflow rule can look at, but that's seriously awful.

Comment: I'm realizing an Approval Process would require the senior most content editors to click "Submit for Approval" then "Approve" on each article, even if that happened to fix this problem. So terrible solution as well.

Comment: What's the workflow rule do? Do you need it to run immediately or can you do something like a scheduled apex class to run hourly to perform the same work as the workflow rule?

Comment: It's a series of Time-Based email alerts, e.g. "send a "due in a week" email 7 days before Due_Date__c, send a "due" email 0 hours after, send a "overdue" email 3 days after, etc. I guess I could have the hourly job find any articles published in the last hour and then perform the process I described in the first comment. I'm desperate so I'll try that out in a test org. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I would just add a field to track once you have sent the email to help avoid duplicate emails but I think a scheduled job would work perfectly for your needs. Ill add an answer

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments,

Since you're using it to send "due" emails, a scheduled apex class is probably your best bet. I've done this for a university I used to work for.

Create new fields to track the emails you're sending like a first warning, second warning and overdue fields, probably date/time fields, to track when you send emails. This will help you audit your employees (we've sent you three emails on x y and z days and you still haven't addressed the article) as well as prevent duplicate emails from going out (only send if the respective field is not null).